# Pandas: take the minimum value from a column with two values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

What I have is the below dataframe.

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
ID     datetime        impressions
cc2    1/2/2016 12:00  1,200           
svd    1/2/2016 12:00  1,080            
xz4    1/2/2016 12:15  1,480     
xgb    1/2/2016 12:15  1,214        
xz4    1/2/2016 12:30  1,157     
x4y    1/2/2016 12:30  1,049
```

What I want would be the following:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
ID     datetime        impressions        
svd    1/2/2016 12:00  1,080              
xgb    1/2/2016 12:15  1,214       
x4y    1/2/2016 12:30  1,049
```

I think this can be achieved by groupby() but I haven't been able to accomplish it yet.

There is unfortunately no additional column I can use to filter the impressions values (for some reason this is how Nielsen structures their data.)

Comment: can you please explain the logic of the operation? i.e. why do you have 3 lines of output - when you have only 2 unique dates?

Comment: sorry i've edited; i miswrote the second portion of the datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclear why your desired output has 3 rows but the following does what you want:

```
In [113]:
df.loc[df.groupby('datetime')['impressions'].idxmin()]

Out[113]:
    ID        datetime  impressions
1  svd  1/2/2016 12:00        1.080
5  x4y  1/2/2016 12:15        1.049
```

Basically we [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on 'datetime' and call [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin) on the 'impressions' column and use the returned indices to index into the main df

Comment: sorry ed, i miswrote the index! was i the process of editing as you responded.

Comment: i believe so; i'm rewriting the datetime column right now to check for some errors. can you explain how the SeriesGroupBy object behaves? i've never seen that used before.

Comment: Which bit? Basically we `groupby` on a single column and then I specifically access a single column, here 'impressions' and call `idxmin`

Comment: perfect; i didn't know it returned indices. i guess i should readup on `idxmin()` ; i assume because you're returning indices and not values you can't use `min()` as they'd yield different results? e.g. `df.groupby('datetime')['impressions'].min()`